# Confused with potential is a and has a relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, oop

I am trying to configure a new database design seeing as we have decided to make the move to Hibernate. Previously in my Java code I had the following three classes

**Super class**

```
public abstract class Card {
    
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    ...
}
```

**A card sub class**

```
public class ContactCard extends Card{
    private String variable1;
    private String variable2;
    private String variable3;

    public ContactCard(){

        super(firstname, lastname, email);
        ...
    }
}
```

And a few others to follow. This seemed to work fine. However I am starting to get a little confused. Here we have the subclasses in *is a* relationships, some card **is a** card. I am failing to map this in to database tables though.

For example, to incorporate the process of a card table in the database I could have a table for each sub class type, and inside this table i could have an id which references a card table (which is generated when a user registers). But, this now means that in my database I have transformed the is a relationship in to has a? *The subclass now has a card rather than is a card.*

I am confused and hope someone can clear things up for me.

Thanks

Comment: Relational databases don't have the concept of inheritance. So you have to choose a way to represent inheritance using the relational concepts. There are 3 strategies, described in length in the documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3285. If the databases understood objects directly, you wouldn't need an ORM, whose role is precisely to map objects concepts to relational concepts, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion stems from the fact that the ORM has to translate objects to relations and vice versa. *is a* is a relation that means a subclass in OOP terms, a class that extends the **base class**. However, in RDBMS terms you have relations (or tables, the two mean the same thing) and records/entities that belong to said relations.

Now, if you have a table that is mapped to your `Card` class, then the subclass (I will call it `MyCard` for now) cannot be inherited per se in your RDBMS, since there is no inheritance. So, instead of inheriting the record, some convention is needed in order to **represent** that concept instead.

If `MyCard` has a `foreign key` mapped to `Card`, then this means that there is a many-to-one relation (as long as `Card` does not have a `foreign key` as well, in which case there would be a one-to-one relation).

If I would have to create an *is a* relation in the table, then the first (but not best) idea I would come up with would be to have a `foreign key` both in the `Card` and the `MyCard` relation towards each-other, because this would technically force that the relation between the two tables is not being duplicated. However, what if you have a `MyCard` base relation and some other possible relations, like `MyCard1`, `MyCard2`, ... `MyCard999` and your `Card` does not necessarily have matches to each of them, then your `Card` relation would be filled with 999 fields that rarely have values.

Even if there is a single `MyCard` relation, having a `foreign key` from `Card` to it is unnecessary, because, if we are consistently using it as an *is a* relation, then **it will be an is a** relation rather than a *has a*, even if there is no technical difference between the two representations.

As a result, it is better to only create a `foreign key` from `MyCard` to `Card` only, because then

- your schema is as simple as possible
- your schema is as easy to be maintained as possible

So, how can we represent this in OOP?

We can have a field in `MyCard` that represents the `Card`.

In short: this looks like an *is a* relation, but since it is consistently used as a *has a* relation, it is essentially a *has a* relation.